# if statement to verify page id

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to add a class="active" statement to a dynamic li element based on if it's meets a requirement of a pageID being equal to a variable named thisPage but I have the syntax messed up. My problem is how do I add my if statement into the middle of a string?  I think I have the spirit captured below....
Thanks

```
<? ...........
  $menu .= "\t<li" . ' if $thisPage=={$pageID} echo class="active"' . "><a href=\"{$pval['link']}\">{$pval['menuTitle']}</a></li>\n";
...........
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary

```
$menu .= '<li'.($thisPage==$pageID?' class="active"':'').'></li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$menu .= "\t<li".($thisPage==$pageID ? ' class="active"' : '').'><a href="'.$pval['link'].'">'.$pval['menuTitle'].'</a></li>'."\n";
```

Though I'd recommend using sprintf to make what's going on clearer

```
$menu .= sprintf('\t<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>',
                     ($thisPage==$pageID ? ' class="active"' : ''),
                     $pval['link'],
                     $pval['menuTitle']);
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way would be to use a [ternary operator](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) like this:

```
$menu .= "\t<li" . $thisPage=={$pageID} ? 'class="active"' : '' . "><a href=\"{$pval['link']}\">{$pval['menuTitle']}</a></li>\n";
```